# Can't make options attribute to work with angular-google-maps to hide cities' names

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I just started using Angular.js (which is fantastic by the way) and need to integrate google maps to my project.

I found out about [Google Maps for AngularJS](http://angular-google-maps.org/) but I'm struggling with something.

I'm trying to hide the cities' names from my map using the options attribute but can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know the styles array has to be

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

because I got it from the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

So what I did was this

**view.html**

```
<google-map 
    center="map.center" 
    options="map.options" 
    zoom="map.zoom">
</google-map>
```

**controller.js**

```
var stylesArray = [{
    featureType: 'administrative.locality',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'off'
    }]
  }];

 $scope.map = {
    center: {
      latitude: 45,
      longitude: -73
    },
    zoom: 8,
    options: [{
      styles: stylesArray
    }]
  };
```

I have tried with quotes, without quotes and combinations of esoterical stuff but I never succeeded to make it work.

I tried with [allenhwkim's angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) but I have not been successful either.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to instantiate the underlying type that Google maps api expects. Namely MapTypeStyle. For a lot of these specialty options the API is very particular.

Answer (score 0):

The `$scope.map.options` should be expression that is not in an array:

```js
var stylesArray = [{
    featureType: 'administrative.locality',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'off'
    }]
  }];

 $scope.map = {
    center: {
      latitude: 45,
      longitude: -73
    },
    zoom: 8,
    options: {
      maxZoom: 20,
      minZoom: 3,
      styles: stylesArray
    }
  };
```